# XML Parsing in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I want add the new node as parent node of the old nodes in XML using C#. for example node have the following XMl file:

```
<bookstore>
   <books>
      <author>
      </author>
   </books> 
</bookstore>
```

like that now I want add the new like below:

```
<bookstore>
 <newnode>
   <books>
      <author>
      </author>
   </books> 
 </newnode>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? LINQ to XML is generally nicer if you've got 3.5 to play with.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("BookStore.xml");
XmlElement newNode = doc.CreateElement("newnode");
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newNode);
newNode.AppendChild(doc.SelectSingleNode("/bookstore/books"));
doc.Save("BookStore.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have VS here so can't confirm that this works but something like this:

```
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.Load("oldxmlfile.xml");
XmlNode oldNode = xd["nameOfRootNode"];
xd.RemoveAll();
XmlNode newParent = xd.CreateNode("nodename");
newParent.AppendChild(oldNode);
xd.AppendChild(newParent);
xd.Save("newXmlFile.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the old node, append the clone, and remove the original:

(edit; I forgot that [AppendChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild.aspx) will move the node if it is already there... no need to clone and remove...)

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
// load the current xml
doc.LoadXml(xml);
// create a new "newnode" node and add it into the tree
XmlElement newnode = (XmlElement) doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("newnode"));
// locate the original "books" node and move it
newnode.AppendChild(doc.SelectSingleNode("/bookstore/books"));
// show the result
Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
```